# Eager spool for update and delete on partitioned table

Tags: partitioning, index-spool

When I update or delete on partition table it shows eager spool in execution plan.

**Image for Update query execution plan showing eager spool:-**
[image: Image for Update query execution plan showing eager spool]

I can’t understand why it is doing eager spool only when I am updating or deleting on partition table, same query when I run on non partition table it does not do eager spool.

Comment: Can you add a script repro-ing this so we can see what your exact situation is in case any of it makes any difference and forces a wide update plan (e.g. in terms of whether the indexes are partition aligned any unique constraints etc)

Answer (score 6):

The eager spool has to do with the size of data you're deleting.

In this case, you're updating a large quantity of rows on a table with several indexes. You're also updating a field that's covered by a lot of nonclustered indexes, and SQL Server has to update all of those indexes as well.

To avoid this operation, update less rows (as a percentage of the table) or index the table less heavily.

Comment: The thickness of the arrows doesn't look as though a large quantity of rows is being updated.

Comment: Martin you are right i am not updating large quantity of rows.
I am updating single row at a time, but the columns that i am updating includes a column "starttime" which is my partition key, also some columns on which indexes are their.

Comment: Hi Brent, Thanks for reply.
I had a BOOKING table, I created a copy of this table BOOKING_PART and partitioned this table.

Now when i update or delete BOOKING_PART it shows eager spool.

Whereas when i update or delete BOOKING it does not shows eager spool.

Both tables are exactly same with same indexes.

Comment: @PuneetPathak - Yes I think if you update the partitioning key that might force a wide plan.